# Is there a way to detect whether a skype call is in progress? (dbus? pulseaudio usage?)

Tags: skype, dbus, interrupts

I built a little gadget that hangs on my office door. I can light it up via a script on my computer to indicate I'm busy and people shouldn't enter. I'd like to run that script, a.k.a. signalling I'm busy, whenever I'm in a Skype call.

Is there a way to detect if I'm in a Skype call and running a script then?

I was thinking dbus and monitor pulseaudio usage, but have no idea where to start. Can somebody point me in the right direction? Ideal would be an interrupt- or event listener-type of thing in python.

#### Edit:

There is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33250864/getting-signals-working-on-pulseaudios-dbus-interface) that isn't quiet it and doesn't work with my version of Ubuntu (16.04).

[mplugd](https://github.com/anyc/mplugd) also seems promising.

Comment: Yeah, that app seems to support that see https://github.com/anyc/mplugd/blob/master/examples/action.d/02-example.rules

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work because it requires pyPortMidi, which is so old, it won't install.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this may not be the perfect but it is good shell prototype using `pactl` for monitoring.

Here a part of output when a call is running:

**`pactl list source-outputs`**

```
Source Output #2
    Driver: protocol-native.c
    Owner Module: 8
    Client: 11
    Source: 2
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Format: pcm, format.sample_format = "\"s16le\""  format.rate = "44100"  format.channels = "2"  format.channel_map = "\"front-left,front-right\""
    Corked: no
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    Buffer Latency: 0 usec
    Source Latency: 66 usec
    Resample method: n/a
    Properties:
        application.icon_name = "chromium-browser"
        media.name = "RecordStream"
        application.name = "Chrome input"
        native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "30"
        application.process.id = "17053"
        application.process.user = "sneetsher"
        application.process.host = "sneetsher-blueskies"
        application.process.binary = "skypeforlinux"
        window.x11.display = ":0.0"
        application.language = "en_US.UTF-8"
        application.process.machine_id = "00074bc0a72a47d49284ce5b9bcda899"
        application.process.session_id = "c4"
        module-stream-restore.id = "source-output-by-application-name:Chrome input"
```

**`pactl list sink-inputs`**

```
Sink Input #166
    Driver: protocol-native.c
    Owner Module: 8
    Client: 16
    Sink: 1
    Sample Specification: float32le 2ch 44100Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Format: pcm, format.sample_format = "\"float32le\""  format.rate = "44100"  format.channels = "2"  format.channel_map = "\"front-left,front-right\""
    Corked: no
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    Buffer Latency: 51519 usec
    Sink Latency: 11124 usec
    Resample method: copy
    Properties:
        application.icon_name = "chromium-browser"
        media.name = "Playback"
        application.name = "Skype for Linux Beta"
        native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "30"
        application.process.id = "17053"
        application.process.user = "sneetsher"
        application.process.host = "sneetsher-blueskies"
        application.process.binary = "skypeforlinux"
        window.x11.display = ":0.0"
        application.language = "en_US.UTF-8"
        application.process.machine_id = "00074bc0a72a47d49284ce5b9bcda899"
        application.process.session_id = "c4"
        module-stream-restore.id = "sink-input-by-application-name:Skype for Linux Beta"

Sink Input #167
    Driver: protocol-native.c
    Owner Module: 8
    Client: 17
    Sink: 1
    Sample Specification: float32le 2ch 44100Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Format: pcm, format.sample_format = "\"float32le\""  format.rate = "44100"  format.channels = "2"  format.channel_map = "\"front-left,front-right\""
    Corked: no
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    Buffer Latency: 28480 usec
    Sink Latency: 11061 usec
    Resample method: copy
    Properties:
        application.icon_name = "chromium-browser"
        media.name = "Playback"
        application.name = "Skype for Linux Beta"
        native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "30"
        application.process.id = "17053"
        application.process.user = "sneetsher"
        application.process.host = "sneetsher-blueskies"
        application.process.binary = "skypeforlinux"
        window.x11.display = ":0.0"
        application.language = "en_US.UTF-8"
        application.process.machine_id = "00074bc0a72a47d49284ce5b9bcda899"
        application.process.session_id = "c4"
        module-stream-restore.id = "sink-input-by-application-name:Skype for Linux Beta"
```

Comment: Thanks. That is one step closer. I figure there should be a dbus signal or event interface or something. I don't necessarily want to query the command continuously in the background.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I got it. It's still rough around the edges and only tested on Ubuntu 16.04 with Python 2.7 but whatever:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
# This monitors pulseaudio streams via a dbus event-listener.
#
# On Ubuntu to enable pulseaudio dbus support:
#
#   echo -e '.ifexists module-dbus-protocol.so\nload-module module-dbus-protocol\n.endif' >> ~/.pulse/pulse/default.pa
#   # globally: /etc/pulse/default.pa
#
# And restart pulseaudio:
#
#   pkill pulseaudio; pulseaudio
#

from __future__ import division, print_function, unicode_literals
import dbus, os, gobject, logging
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop
from logging import info, debug, error, warning as warn
#logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

skypestream = []
cstr = 'org.PulseAudio.Core1'

# convert byte array to string
def dbus2str(db):
    if type(db)==dbus.Struct:
        return str(tuple(dbus2str(i) for i in db))
    if type(db)==dbus.Array:
        return "".join([dbus2str(i) for i in db])
    if type(db)==dbus.Dictionary:
        return dict((dbus2str(k), dbus2str(v)) for k, v in db.items())
    if type(db)==dbus.String:
        return db+''
    if type(db)==dbus.UInt32:
        return str(db+0)
    if type(db)==dbus.Byte:
        return chr(db)
    if type(db)==dbus.Boolean:
        return db==True
    if type(db)==dict:
        return dict((dbus2str(k), dbus2str(v)) for k, v in db.items())
    return "(%s:%s)" % (type(db), db)


def sig_handler(path=None, sender=None, msg=None):
    debug( '\n\npath: %s\n%s\n\nsender: %s\n%s\n\nmsg: %s\n%s\n\n',
        path, dir(path), sender, dir(sender), msg, dir(msg) )
    mem = msg.get_member()
    dbus_pstreams = (
        dbus.Interface(
            pulse_bus.get_object(object_path=path),
            dbus_interface='org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties'
        ) for path in core1.Get(
            cstr,
            'PlaybackStreams',
            dbus_interface='org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties' )
        )

    pstreams = {}
    for pstream in dbus_pstreams:
        try:
            pstreams[pstream.Get(cstr+'.Stream', 'Index')] =  pstream
        except dbus.exceptions.DBusException:
            pass
    if pstreams:
        for stream in pstreams.keys():
            plist = pstreams[stream].Get(cstr+'.Stream', 'PropertyList')
            appname = dbus2str(plist.get('application.name', None))
            if mem == 'PlaybackStreamRemoved' and path in skypestream:
                skypestream.remove(path)
                print('no-skype')
            if appname.find('Skype') > -1:
                if mem == 'NewPlaybackStream':
                    skypestream.append(path)
                    print('busy', appname)


def pulse_bus_address():
    address = None
    if 'PULSE_DBUS_SERVER' in os.environ:
        address = os.environ['PULSE_DBUS_SERVER']
    else:
        bus = dbus.SessionBus()
        server_lookup = bus.get_object("org.PulseAudio1",
            "/org/pulseaudio/server_lookup1")
        address = server_lookup.Get("org.PulseAudio.ServerLookup1",
            "Address", dbus_interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties")
        debug(address)
    if not address: raise RuntimeError('No pulseaudio dbus address found!')
    return address


if __name__ == "__main__":
    DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)

    loop = gobject.MainLoop()

    pulse_bus = dbus.connection.Connection(pulse_bus_address())
    core1 = pulse_bus.get_object(object_path='/org/pulseaudio/core1')

    core1.ListenForSignal(cstr+'.NewPlaybackStream', dbus.Array(signature="o"))
    core1.ListenForSignal(cstr+'.PlaybackStreamRemoved', dbus.Array(signature="o"))

    pulse_bus.add_signal_receiver(sig_handler, message_keyword='msg')

    loop.run()
```